# Wifi password connection problem

Tags: wi-fi

When I enter my password on my phone (Motorola) to connect to wifi it says it is incorrect but it's not. How can I fix this?

Comment: Which device and Android version is it?

Answer (score 2):

in the list of wifi networks, try the following:

- long press on the network that has this issue
- choose 'forget' to let Android forget the stored password
- tap on the network again (it will now only show when it's in range) to try and

connect and Android will ask you for the password.